# Laravel Echo + Pusher: request to broadcasting/auth returns login page

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-echo, pusher-js

I updated my application from 5.2 to 5.3 to broadcast notifications with Pusher, but when pusher try to authenticate current logged in user over `broadcasting/auth`,  I got an error:

`Pusher : No callbacks on private-App.Models.Client.9 for pusher:subscription_error`

in the browser console->network->xhr, I found that the request to `broadcasting/auth` not giving me the `auth:{token}` object, but returning my login page instead !!!

I think it is a problem with middleware but I can't find it.

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php:**

```
public function boot()
{
    // Broadcast::routes();
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:client']]);

    /*
     * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
     */
    Broadcast::channel('App.Models.Client.*', function ($user, $userId) {
        return true;
    });

}
```

**app.js:** after importing pusher-js & Laravel Echo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// check if there's a logged in user
if(Laravel.clientId) {
    window.Echo.private(`App.Models.Client.${Laravel.clientId}`)
        .notification((notification) => {
            console.log(notification);
            addNotifications([notification], '#notifications');
        });
} });
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of pulling my hair, I finally found the cause of this issue. I was using a package for Authentication/Authorization called `cartalyst/sentinel` which is great except that once installed it will entirely replace the Laravel default auth behavior. So any request to `broadcasting/auth` is actually rejected.

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel version > 5.3 & Pusher, you need add token in header request, your code in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

it worked for me, and hope it help you.