# Laravel pusher broadcasting/auth 500 issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am adding the code to avoid this error

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

i only have the following configuration here

```
PUSHER_APP_ID
PUSHER_APP_KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET
```

Question is : i want to know what is this `YourTokenLogin` thing here? what should i paste here?

Comment: Is this similar to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598822/laravel-echo-pusher-request-to-broadcasting-auth-returns-login-page

Comment: @AliBabaAzimi no, its not the solution of my problem